# How can I extract the first frame of an animated gif using ImageMagick's convert utility from STDIN?

Tags: imagemagick

**I have seen information about how to process images using the '-' filename to process images from STDIN to STDOUT.**

`$ convert logo: gif:- | display gif:-`

**I have read how to extract a single frame from an animated gif.**

`$ convert 'images.gif[0]' image.png`

**I have not found any information about how to extract the first frame of a gif from STDIN.**

I've tried `convert -[0]` and `convert -'[0]'` to no avail.  Can you help?

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php

Answer (score 12):

**It turns out that `convert -'[0]'` works.**

I was mistaken.  Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 7):

The above-mentioned answer is correct, but I just like to make it more clear.

to extract all frames to separate image files

```
convert images.gif image.png
```

to extract the first frame :

```
convert 'images.gif[0]' image.png
```